# Disable scroll until div is hidden on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, touch

So if this has been answered then please direct me to the correct place...I think most of the reason I cant find the answer to this is because I cant figure out how to ask it properly haha.

I'm building a mobile website. Check out nim.matthewjonat.com then inspect with chrome and push ctrl+shift+m and then you'll be in a similar environment to me without having to look at a mobile.

I have a div which goes over everything and there is an arrow at the bottom which you need to click to look at the rest of the site.

What I'm thinking though is that if you first visit the page on a mobile you are going to instinctively want to scroll before you figure out you need to click the arrow. This is fine but if you scroll even while that first div is there (it is position:fixed) the content underneath scrolls but that first div just sits there so you could potentially be at the bottom of the page before you figure out you have to click the arrow to see the site.

I'm guessing this will involve some form of javascript which is fine. I'm just really not sure where to look....

The thing is I'm not even sure its the scrolling I want to disable seeing as its a mobile? Do I need to disable some kind of touch event until someone has clicked the arrow?

Thanks in advance!

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with CSS, starting at the `body` element.

```
  body.show-overlay {
    overflow:hidden; 
  }
  body.show-overlay .overlay {
    display:block;
  }
  .overlay {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;left:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.75);
  }
```

When the body has the class `show-overlay`, overflow will be hidden and the overlay will show. Then use JS for the click event handler to remove the class from the body

```
document.getElementById('close-overlay').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var body = document.body;
    var className = 'show-overlay';

    if (body.classList) {
      body.classList.remove(className);
    }
    else {
      body.className = body.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
    }
})
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this but maybe I didnt explain correctly. The content underneath the overlay needs to stop scrolling when the overlay is showing. I tried adding your classes and css rules but it didnt work like that. The content underneath still scrolls while the overlay is there....thanks anyway....

Comment: I know that... works fine [on this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/banoti/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: OK so I took an in-depth look at this and it doesnt work on a mobile...you can load it in js bin in a separate window, then in chrome push ctrl+shift+m to emulate mobile. It still lets you scroll? I havent actually tried this on a mobile yet...I will upload and try later...

Comment: Works fine for me on mobile as well.